Moodle app pod is not connecting to external B
I have deployed the Moodle into my GKE cluster using helm chart. I have set the min replica count to 3, and max count to 10. the first pod that is created in the cluster got connected to the external database by running few queries, but the next created pods are not getting connected to the db and showing the below error log.
I want all the pods to get connected to the db and only start Read and write the data. please help.
shivakumar_c@cloudshell:~ (devops-414505)$ kubectl logs moodle-4665fd8f-vcztk 
moodle 09:41:29.03 INFO ==> ** Starting Moodle setup ** 
moodle 09:41:29.12 DEBUG ==> Validating settings in APACHE_* environment variables 
moodle 09:41:29.14 DEBUG ==> Copying files from /opt/bitnami/apache/conf.default to /opt/bitnami/apache/conf 
moodle 09:41:47.94 INFO ==> Validating settings in MYSQL_CLIENT_* env vars 
moodle 09:41:48.14 DEBUG ==> Validating settings in MOODLE_* environment variables... 
moodle 09:41:48.42 INFO ==> Ensuring Moodle directories exist 
moodle 09:41:48.43 INFO ==> Trying to connect to the database server 
moodle 09:41:48.44 DEBUG ==> Executing SQL command:SELECT 1 /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysql: Deprecated program name. It will be removed in a future release, use '/opt /bitnami/mysql/bin/mariadb' insteadcontainers 
moodle 09:41:48.62 INFO ==> Running Moodle install script Moodle 4.4 (Build: 20240422) command line installation program Database tables already present; CLI installation cannot continue.

I want all the pods to get connected to the external db and they should not run the queries to create table schema, instead they just connect and start Read&write.
